# Is there a way to convert all haven_labelled data to something that can be used for linear regression/scatter plots/etc?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-haven

As mentioned in the title, a lot of my data seems to be haven_labelled which means that any command I've been using on it in R keeps getting rejected in a way. I don't really know what to do.

Is there a way to convert them to something useable in R?

I can't seem to find a specific command that works online. I've been trying to figure out how to use lapply, etc but it doesn't seem to be working.

I saw this command online which is:

```
data2 <- data %>%
 mutate(across(all_of(col_names), as.factor))
```

which apparently would convert the entire thing to an r factor but it just returned this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(all_of(col_names), as.factor)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while evaluating `all_of(col_names)`.
Caused by error in `as_indices_impl()`:
! object 'col_names' not found
```

I also tried specifying a col_name but it returned something similar as well.

Table() command won't work due to this though, attributes() does return observations:

```
attributes(data$sgnptit)
$label
[1] "Signed petition last 12 months"

$format.stata
[1] "%1.0f"

$class
[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"        

$labels
Yes  No 
  1   2
```

Comment: The `as_factor()` function would apply the labels into the factor variables, just run `mydf <- haven::as_factor(mydf)`

Comment: You did specify `col_names` as `col_names = names(data)` before, didn't you?

Comment: Hi Phil, I tried to use that command and whilst it did work commands like table() and attribute(), using with select() or ggplot brings up:  satisfaction_gov <- select(stfgov, stfeco, gndr, agea, eduyrs, ctzcntr)
Error in select(stfgov, stfeco, gndr, agea, eduyrs, ctzcntr) : 
  object 'stfgov' not found